# Conditional expectation and set times random variable??

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, finance

On [page 62](http://www.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/fin1/ifnotes.pdf), what in the world is the meaning of equation (5.2)?

$\mathcal{F}_t$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, so $Z_t \in \mathcal{F}_t$ is a set. $X_u$ is a random variable, so what is $Z_t X_u$?

Comment: This is one of the basic properties of conditional expectation ("pulling out what's known"): if $X$ and $Y$ are integrable (i.e. $\in \mathcal{L}^1$) and $X$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$, then $$\mathbb{E}[XY \ | \ \mathcal{F}] = X  \mathbb{E}[Y \ | \ \mathcal{F}] \ \ \text{a.s.} $$
You can find the proof, for example, [here, page 5, property 6](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/conditional_expectation.pdf#page=5).

Comment: $Z$ is not a set, it is random variable. Really, $\mathbb{E}[Z_t \ | \ \mathcal{F}_t] = Z_t$ cannot indicate a set, because the conditional expectation is a random variable by definition. Looks like the notation $Z_t \in \mathcal{F}$ is just an indication of measurability for them.